# UK population and NHS spending projections

Tags: regression, forecasting, prediction, demography

Say I want to make some projection about the size of the UK population 25 years from now and consider the impact of this population growth on national health spending. Is the following approach reasonable?

- Let $X_t$ be the UK population in year $t$ and assume that $X_{t+1} = X_t + b_{t-1} - d_{t-1} + m_{t-1}$, with $b, \ d, \ m$ being births, deaths and net migration respectively.
- Fit birth, death and migration rates to census data using linear regression and run an iterative simulation to find predicted population at any given year.
- For predicting national health spending per capita, run a further linear regression on historic total spending figures (with time as the predictor) and divide the projected spending by the projected population.

Is this OK as a basic approach and is there a better way to do this?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.